# Switching up senses

Tags: brain, sensory-perception

What if you change the connections of the brain to where the eye is connected to the part of the brain that creates taste. Will it start to adapt and begin to see with that part of the brain? Or will it instead start taking the information from the eyes and converting it into taste?

Comment: [A related question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9135/7001) on sensory substitution and Bach-y-Rita's "seeing with the tongue" project.

Comment: Pls take the time to answer or contact someone who can answer, I have had way too many negative experiences with toxic users of this site that my patience has ran thin with comment police.

Comment: @nonametheastronaut When you post questions that don't meet the site standards for question quality and showing some effort towards framing the question you're going to find negative receptions. That's not toxicity, it's responding to the rudeness of expecting people to put effort into answering your question when you haven't put effort into asking. People are completely volunteer here, there's no requirement that anyone answer at all.

Comment: If you are getting negative experiences, maybe you need to look at what is causing them? Our [tour] and [meta] may help. We work differently to many SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.